# PyPy and CPython: are big performance increases planned?

Tags: python, performance, jit, pypy

While I know projects promising large speed gains can result in let downs, I don't see much in the way of a roadmap for speeding up CPython and/or PyPy.

Is there something planned that promises a huge boost in speed for the core interpreter (e.g. [--with-computed-gotos](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.1.html#optimizations)) in either of them? How about their standard libraries (e.g. [Decimal in C](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#decimal), [IO in C](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#optimizations))?

I know [HotPy(2)](https://sites.google.com/site/makingcpythonfast/) has an outline of a plan for speeding CPython up, but it sounds like an one-man project without much traction in core CPython.

PyPy has [some information](http://pypy.org/performance.html) about where performance isn't great, but I can find no big goals for speedup in the docs.

So, are there known targets that could bring big performance improvement for Python implementations?

Comment: PyPy improved by a factor of 3 in less than two years.  What more do you expect?  That they tell you in advance how much faster they will be next year?

Comment: It'd probably be much more interesting if you asked a question about code you wish to further optimise.

Comment: @TryPyPy - What type of programs do you write/use that need performance improvements? What areas of those programs need improvement? Have you asked the PyPy and CPython developers for help or indications of when things might change on those areas?

Comment: @SvenMarnach They used to blog more about exciting upcoming improvements, so yes :) And I'd really like to know more about CPython here: they didn't merge Unladen and don't talk much about improving speed in general.

Comment: @TryPyPy: They didn't merge Unladen because the project was abandoned.

Comment: @bernie Agreed, but what little code I write these days isn't really performance sensitive. I'm hoping there's some value in more general questions like this one, but am ready to accept if there isn't.

Comment: @SvenMarnach ISTM they didn't merge because the merge effort was abandoned: the merging PEP was accepted, then withdrawn -> http://svn.python.org/view/peps/trunk/pep-3146.txt?view=markup&pathrev=79008

Comment: @TryPyPy: See the withdrawal notice in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/ and the first reference therein.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You're right, thanks for correcting my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll answer the part about PyPy. I can't speak for CPython, but I think there are performance improvements that are being worked on (don't quote me on this though).

There is no project plan, since it's really not working that way. All the major parts (like "JIT" or "Garbage Collection") has been essentially done, however that completely does not mean everything is fast. There are definitely things that are slow and we generally improve on a case by case basis - submit a bug report if you think something is too slow. I have quite a few performance improvements on my plate that would definitely help twisted, but I have no idea about others.

Big things that are being worked on that might be worth mentioning:

- Improved frames, that should help recursion and function calls that are not inlined (for example that contain loops)
- Better string implementations for various kinds of usages, like concatenation, slicing etc.
- Faster tracing
- More compact tuples and objects, storing unwrapped results

Can I promise when how or how much it'll speed up things? Absolutely not, but on average we manage to have 10-30% speed improvements release-to-release, which is usually every 4 months or so, so I guess some stuff will get faster, but without you giving me a crystal ball or a time machine, I won't tell you for sure.

Cheers,
fijal

Comment: Since asking this question, I've found two links by yourself with interesting projects/goals/issues: http://lostinjit.blogspot.com/2012/02/pypy-and-its-future-challenges.html and http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/project-ideas.html. I suggest consolidating these and your answer as a post in the official blog: show people that there are a lot of known potential improvements and they'll infer a lot of improvements will happen sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

Your comments belie a lot of confusion...
PyPy and Python have currently very different performance capabilities.
Pypy is currently more than 5x faster than CPython on average.
HotPy has nothing to do with CPython. It's a one-man project and it's a whole new VM (not yet released, so I can't say anything about it's performance).

At the moment, there's a lot of activity in the PyPy project and they are improving it day by day.
There's a numpy port in a very advanced stage of development, they are improving ctypes, Cython compatibility, and soon there will be a complete Python3 implementation.

I believe PyPy is currently on pair with the V8 JavaScript engine and similar projects in terms of performance.
If speed and Python is what you want, pay attention to this project.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the current situation (e.g. http://speed.pypy.org), but I was looking for plans for improvement, like http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/ProjectPlan. See the link in the question for HotPy(2): it's now a proposal to speed CPython up, but still looks like a solo project.

Comment: Hey, you are right! I didn't know about Hotpy(2). I knew about the original Hotpy project by Mark Shannon, but it wasn't related to cpython at all. As for Unladen Swalow, unfortunately it went nowhere and now the project is dead...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that PyPy *is* the plan to speed up CPython. PyPy aims to be an extremely conformant python interpreter which is highly optimized. The project has collected together all of the benchmarks they could find, and runs all of them for each build of pypy, to ensure against performance regressions. Check it out: http://speed.pypy.org/

I believe that by the time that the performance of cpython won't cut it anymore (for web dev work), pypy will be completely ready for prime-time. Raymond Hettinger (a core python dev) has called PyPy "python with the optimizations turned on".